# Impossible to click on element on iOS devices for Appium XCUITEST driver

Tags: click, appium, webdriver-io, appium-ios, xcuitest

I am using next automation stack: Appium + WebdriverIO + Mocha.

- Xcuitest driver version is 7.3.0
- Appium version is 2.4.1

**Case:**
On one of the screen I have modal with buttons [Yes Logout] and [Cancel]
In Appium inspector I have accessibilityIDs for both these buttons and I can find them. But I can not click on them.

I have tried to use:

- click()
- touchAction('tap')
- mobile: tap  method of XCUITEST driver https://appium.github.io/appium-xcuitest-driver/7.3/reference/execute-methods/#mobile-tap

But nothing helped for me.

Modal with buttons:
[image]